# CSS border-radius + box-shadow in Safari

Tags: safari, css

I made a CSS class to display images rouded with border and some shadows. In Chrome, Firefox all OK, but Safari displays it wrong.

Code used may be found in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpartakusMd/qzKA5/) or below:

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
}
```

How to make it work in Safari?

Screenshots (first is Chrome, Second is Safari):

[image: Chrome] [image: Safari]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2ZGR/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="image-holder">
    <img src="http://data1.whicdn.com/images/33153622/original.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img, .image-holder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 100px;
}

.image-holder {
    border: 5px solid #DDD;

    border-radius: 110px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 110px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 110px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 110px;

    box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;

    background-color: rgb(204,204,204); /* Needed for IEs */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser border-radius

```
     /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
     -webkit-border-radius: 100px; 

     /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
     -moz-border-radius: 100px; 

     /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
     border-radius: 100px;
```

Cross browser box-shadow

```
    background-color: rgb(204,204,204); /* Needed for IEs */

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
```

Final result for your changed css (include filter if you want it for IE as well)

```
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 100px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 100px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 10px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: I tried the Cross browser variant, stil no changes. Same result as before in Safari :(

Answer (score -3):

```
img {
border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
-khtml-border-radius: 100px;
```

}

Comment: You appear to have copied and pasted a segment of CoalaArmy's answer, even the skewed formatting matches it. Not very helpful.

Comment: What can I say while this answer is copied, already tried this and the Gaurav answer which contains yours, and CoalaArmy's answer is already accepted.